# ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number on oci_bind_by_name()

Tags: php, oracle, stored-procedures, blob

I was given the Oracle stored procedure in the code below to retrieve a BLOB from the DB. This is my first time trying to get an Oracle stored procedure to run and I just can't figure out the PHP syntax. I'm running the following and getting...

> Warning: oci_bind_by_name(): ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number

Can anyone tell me what I need to do to get this to work?

```
$connStr = "(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=$db_host)(PORT=$db_port))
            (CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=$db_service_name)(SERVER=dedicated)))";

$conn = oci_connect($db_user , $db_password, $connStr);

$sql = "declare
  l_blob  BLOB;
begin
  GET_BLOB_PROC(INPUT_ID => '123456', IMG_BLOB => l_blob) ;
END;";

$l_blob = oci_new_descriptor($conn, OCI_D_LOB);
$stid = oci_parse($conn, $sql);
oci_bind_by_name($stid, ':l_blob', $l_blob, -1, OCI_B_BLOB);
$r = oci_execute($stid);
```

Comment: Think you need to add the `:` in `IMG_BLOB => :l_blob) ;` to show it's a parameter.

Comment: Thank you Nigel Ren. That was it! Ugggghhh.